# Unable to get intent details in dialogflow rest api v2

Tags: node.js, rest, express, dialogflow-es

I'm using dialogflow api v2, REST version with nodejs. This application is meant to be a middleware serving as a bridge for another application. Below is the code I'm using in my model class:

```
static async GetIntent(intentName) {
        let intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient();
        let intent = await intentsClient.getIntent({ name: intentName, intentView: Dialogflow.IntentView.INTENT_VIEW_FULL });
        return intent[0];
    }
```

and this is controller class code:

```
static async GetIntent(req, res) {
        try {
            let intent = await Dialogflow.GetIntent(req.params.intentName);
            res.json({
                intent,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            CustomError.Handle(err, res);
        }
    }
```

and this is the router code:

```
router.get('/getIntent', DialogflowController.GetIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is some change with your Payload,

Please Try this way,

```
static async GetIntent(req, res) {
    try {
        const request = {
            name: `projects/${config.project_id}/agent/intents/${config.intent_id}`
        }
        let intent = await Dialogflow.GetIntent(request);
        res.json({
            intent,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        CustomError.Handle(err, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are passing query parameters here please make sure what you are sending before calling Dialogflow api. It must have format i mentioned above. I have tested and its working